# HTML div width fit image

Tags: html, css, image

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<img src = "http://www.flowerpicturegallery.com/d/1977-3/yellow+daisy+flower+picture.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I use the above code to display an image. Code works good excepct two facts: 1) How can I make the div's width fit the image (stop where image stops)? I tried `width: auto;` or `width: 100%;` but none of them works... And 2) why is there a very small blank area at the bottom and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="child-width">
    <img src = "http://www.flowerpicturegallery.com/d/1977-3/yellow+daisy+flower+picture.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.child-width {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block; // add this
}
```

Check this [example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlinph/nhh7aord/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `display: block` to your image, it should fix the blank space,

And as said by @iamdevlinph, add `display: inline-block;` to your div so it can fit your image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<img src = "http://www.flowerpicturegallery.com/d/1977-3/yellow+daisy+flower+picture.jpg">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) How can I make the div's width fit the image (stop where image stops)?

Try with adjusting width of div
   Eg: width: 15%;

or you can add     display: inline-block; for div

2) why is there a very small blank area at the bottom and how can I fix this?
 Add display: block; for image

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code with your old code:

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src = "http://www.flowerpicturegallery.com/d/1977-3/yellow+daisy+flower+picture.jpg">
</div>
```